# Problem adding a dependency in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies, gridle

I am getting a problem when I try to add a dependency in Android Studio. I want to add `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` to dependencies, but I am getting an error like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}

ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Comment: hi, please post all the dependencies you got under dependencies

Comment: Properly format the code (use `CTRL+K` or backticks) and post the manifest merger logs :)

Comment: I have posted all dependencies @Dor

Answer (score 2):

You are using both androidx and android support library. Replace android support library with the existing androidx library.

```
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

You can find their androidx version [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: What's the purpose of the code snippet you provided?

Comment: You need change these library with their respective androidx version.

Comment: Isn't using `com.google.android.material` enough? It includes Support/Design.

Comment: But you can't use both libraries at same time.

Comment: Yeah everyone knows that, it's old news. Just use the package I said since it includes support/design. Your message: `You need change these library with their respective androidx version` is slightly wrong, since not each package requires a AndroidX equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, You are right but sometimes it does not work and create ambiguities. You should review Manifest merging status for getting the exact problem.